# How to assign lambda expression to a variable?

Tags: java, if-statement, java-8

I have a kind of calculator:

```
sum = value1 + value2;
    multiplication = value1 * value2;
    division = (value1 / value2);
    average = (sum / 2);

    if (operation.compareToIgnoreCase("add") == 0)
        result = sum;
    else if (operation.compareToIgnoreCase("mult") == 0)
        result = multiplication;
    else if (operation.compareToIgnoreCase("div") == 0)
        result = division;
    else if (operation.compareToIgnoreCase("avg") == 0)
        result = average;
```

And i have to turn this  to lambda expressions:

```
result = (request.getValue1(), request.getValue2()) -> {
        if (request.getOperation().compareToIgnoreCase("add") == 0) return request.getValue1() + request.getValue2();
        else if (request.getOperation().compareToIgnoreCase("mult") == 0) return request.getValue1() * request.getValue2();
        else if (request.getOperation().compareToIgnoreCase("div") == 0) return request.getValue1() / request.getValue2();
        else if (request.getOperation().compareToIgnoreCase("avg") == 0) return (request.getValue1() + request.getValue2())/2;
    }
```

But it doesnt work. Can you guys help?
Thanks

Comment: This is not the lambda issue but the design issue.

Comment: In addition to everything else, the point of using polymorphism is to use a `Map<String,something>` instead of those `if` statements.

Comment: What you mean with design issue @Nikolas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For example:

```
BiFunction<Number,Number,Number> sum = (value1, value2) -> value1 + value2;
```

and you can use it like this:

```
sum.apply(value1,value2)
```

more examples [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/java.util.function/BiFunction/index.htm).

Also you can store your set of `BiFunction` in a `Map`:

```
Map<String,BiFunction<Number, Number, Number>> operations = new HashMap<>();
operations.put("sum", sum);
```

If you do the same for all operations, you call them as it follows:

```
operations.get("sum").apply(value1, value2);
```

So, the result can be computed as is follows:

```
result = (value1, value2, operation) -> operations.get(operation).apply(value1, value2);
```

Comment: much cleaner would be to define an enum for this

Comment: Yes, you can improve the solution using enums. This is just a basic example, but enumeration fits the use case pretty well and the `get` operation should handle unknown operations.

Comment: Why the lambda at the end? what is this 3-arg lambda?

Comment: To replace the last lambda reported in question.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a map with a String and [`DoubleBinaryOperator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/DoubleBinaryOperator.html) or an [`IntBinaryOperator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntBinaryOperator.html) depends on the type you want like so :

```
Map<String, DoubleBinaryOperator> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("add", (v1, v2) -> v1 + v2);
map.put("mult", (v1, v2) -> v1 * v2);
map.put("div", (v1, v2) -> v1 / v2);
map.put("avg", (v1, v2) -> (v1 * v2) / 2);
```

Then you can call that map with the operation you want for example :

```
// an example
String operation = "add";
Double reslt = map.get(operation).applyAsDouble(3, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

from the example it's not very clear, what `result` should be. So let me rewrite it including types:

```
Function<Request, Double> calculator = (request) -> {
    if (request.getOperation().compareToIgnoreCase("add") == 0) return request.getValue1() + request.getValue2();
    else if (request.getOperation().compareToIgnoreCase("mult") == 0) return request.getValue1() * request.getValue2();
    else if (request.getOperation().compareToIgnoreCase("div") == 0) return request.getValue1() / request.getValue2();
    else if (request.getOperation().compareToIgnoreCase("avg") == 0) return (request.getValue1() + request.getValue2())/2;
    else throw new IllegalArgumentException();
};

double result = calculator.apply(new Request("add", 2, 4));
```